# Is there a standard User Settings Dialog for GWT projects?

Tags: gwt

Is there a standard panel or library available for GWT projects that provides a "user settings" interface similar to what can be found on Android or iOS?

Comment: Standard settings for what?

Comment: For anything.  Android and iOS have generic libraries that allow a programmer to define arbitrary settings.  The system then displays that with a consistent UI.

Answer (score 0):

GWT runs in any modern browser (and some old ones). Each browser/OS combination has its own default styles for buttons, scrollbars, radio buttons, links, etc. GWT results in a standard HTML that renders natively in each browser. Unless you apply your own styles, a button in GWT in Chrome/Windows will look like any "standard" button in Chrome/Windows. The same button (no changes in GWT code) will look differently in Chrome/Mac - it will look like any standard button in Chrome/Mac.

As for the layout of the form (labels, margins, etc.), there is no standard way of doing it in any browser. Your settings page should look like all the other pages in your application.